# jQuery create input field and set focus

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to:

- create a new list item with an input field
- set the focus to that new field

  ```
  $("#newList").click(function () {
      $('li.divider').before('<li class="newListName"><input id="newListNameInput" /></li>',function() {
          $('#newListNameInput').focus();
      });
  });
  ```

The new list item gets created, but no focus.
Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) is synchronous and does not take a callback argument. You only have to write:

```
$("#newList").click(function() {
    $('li.divider').before('<li class="newListName"><input id="newListNameInput" /></li>');
    $('#newListNameInput').focus();
});
```

Or maybe, if you want to take advantage of chaining:

```
$("#newList").click(function() {
    $('<li class="newListName"><input id="newListNameInput" /></li>')
        .insertBefore("li.divider").find("input").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/CWqxk/

Comment: Strangely enough, it works in jsfiddle, doesn't work in my code (no other focus() are called, same jQuery version).

Answer (score 0):

There is no handler as a second parameter of `before`, so just use:

```
$("#newList").click(function() {
    $('li.divider').before('<li class="newListName"><input id="newListNameInput" /></li>');
    $('#newListNameInput').focus();
});
```

*But be careful with duplication of IDs if you add many new `input` elements. Maybe it is better to use classes.*

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CANWE/

Comment: Same deal, works in jsfiddle, doesn't work in my code. (no other focus() are called, same jQuery version)

Comment: @user1613826 Didn't you forget about DOM ready `$(function() { ... });`?

Comment: I didn't, but suddenly it worked. Must have been another syntax or cache issue. Thanks for the help!